# How to load an inlined SVG in Go using GOTK3 and librsvg?

Tags: go, svg

I work on an application written in Go.  It uses GOTK3, librsvg is installed, and I can create (and then display) SVG images using `gtk.ImageNewFromFile(file-path-to-svg)`.

Now I would like to programmatically create an image from an SVG that's inlined within the source code... something like this:

```
color := "#FF0000"
redSvg := 
  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
  "<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n" +
  "<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\" width=\"32px\" height=\"32px\" viewBox=\"0 0 32 32\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 32 32\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n" +
  "    <rect fill=\"" + color + "\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\"/>\n" +
  "</svg>"

image, err := ImageNewFromSvg(redSvg)
.
.
.


func ImageNewFromSvg(svg string) (*gtk.Image, error) {
  ?
}
```

...and I need some help with the implementation of `ImageNewFromSvg()`.  gotk3 doesn't have an `ImageNewFromSvg()` API, but it does have `ImageNewFromPixbuf()`.

I've tried to implement the creation of a pixbuf from a string (with SVG markup), but I haven't been able to do so.

Is it possible to create an image from an inlined SVG, defined within the source code?  If so, what would the implementation of `ImageNewFromSvg()` be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load inlined SVG with `gdk.PixbufNewFromDataOnly` through passing your svg string as slice of bytes to it then getting pixbuf from it and putting it to `gtk.ImageNewFromPixbuf` to get `*gtk.Image` to use it in your window.
And here is one of correct implementation of your mentioned `ImageNewFromSvg` function:

```
func ImageNewFromSvg(svg string) (*gtk.Image, error){
  pixbuf, err := gdk.PixbufNewFromDataOnly([]byte(svg))
  if err !=  nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  
  img, err := gtk.ImageNewFromPixbuf(pixbuf)
  
  if err !=  nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  
  return img, nil
}
```

Example usage in actual gtk program:

```
package main

import (
    "log"

    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gtk"
    "github.com/gotk3/gotk3/gdk"
)

func main() {
    gtk.Init(nil)

    win, err := gtk.WindowNew(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Unable to create window:", err)
    }
    win.SetTitle("Svg Example")
    win.Connect("destroy", func() {
        gtk.MainQuit()
    })


    color := "#FF0000"
    svgdata := "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n" +
               "<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd\">\n" +
               "<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Layer_1\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\" width=\"32px\" height=\"32px\" viewBox=\"0 0 32 32\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 32 32\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n" +
               "    <rect fill=\"" + color + "\" width=\"32\" height=\"32\"/>\n" +
               "</svg>"

    svgImage, err  := ImageNewFromSvg(svgdata)
    
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    
    win.Add(svgImage)
    win.ShowAll()


    gtk.Main()
}  

func ImageNewFromSvg(svg string) (*gtk.Image, error){
  pixbuf, err := gdk.PixbufNewFromDataOnly([]byte(svg))
  if err !=  nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  
  img, err := gtk.ImageNewFromPixbuf(pixbuf)
  
  if err !=  nil {
    return nil, err
  }
  
  return img, nil
}
```

And output:
[image: Visual]

Comment: Thanks @BrokenArmor!  That was exactly what I was looking for!  I missed the `PixbufNewFromDataOnly()` API, but now that you pointed it out, it makes complete sense.